# How to set variables as text inside text_areas using tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to programming in general, and i'm trying to display variables as regular text inside of a text box and i'm unsure how to set it up without it just being displayed as it's variable. For example, Score [s] should be 0 at the beginning of the program, but its just [s], and I want to know how to set it up right. The prblem code is on line 3 btw

```
Text_area = tk.Text(master=window,height=5,width=17,bg='lightblue')
text_area.grid(column=1,row=2)
text = "Your choice: [yc] \nBot Choice : [bc] \nScore : [s]" 
text_area.insert(tk.END,text)
```

Comment: Are `s` and `bc` and `yc` variables? Are they normal python variables or instances of one of the tkinter variable classes? Are you familiar with python's [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)?

Comment: `text = f'Your choice: {yc} \nBot Choice: {bc} \nScore: {s}'` does this help? they are as previously mentioned by Bryan Oakley `f strings`

Comment: Assuming `ys`, `bc` and `s` are variables you can use: `text = "Your choice: " + str(ys) + "\nChoice: " + str(bc) + "\nScore: "+str(s)`

Comment: @Matiiss and BryanOakley isn't it better if you started with the basics instead of going directly to f-strings? OP mentioned that they are quite new to programming

Comment: @TheLizzard I would say that the basics of `f strings` are not that complex, You only need to know to put `f` in front of the string and curly brackets `{}` around the variables in the string and You don't have to use `str()` for every variable that is not string

Comment: @Matiiss Yes but there is a `str` function that was designed for that. I would consider using `str` more basic than using f-strings.

Comment: @TheLizzard: _"isn't it better if you started with the basics instead of going directly to f-strings?"_ I don't think so. f-strings are a very useful feature. However, I'm not saying they should or shouldn't use f-strings, I merely asked if they knew what they were.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#:%7E:text=f-Strings%3A%20A%20New%20and%20Improved%20Way%20to%20Format,You%20are%20a%20comedian.%20...%204%20Speed.%20) and  do something like this -

```py
yc = 1234   #Your val
bc = 4567 #Your val
s = 7890 #Your val

Text_area = tk.Text(master=window,height=5,width=17,bg='lightblue')
text_area.grid(column=1,row=2)
text = f"Your choice: {yc} \nBot Choice : {bc} \nScore : {s}" 
text_area.insert(tk.END,text)
```